# Jest: ReferenceError: uuid is not defined

Tags: angularjs, jestjs

When I am testing an angularjs directive using jest, in directive compile, I have used uuid.v4() to generate id for directive, there will be an error when I test this directive, "ReferenceError: uuid is not defined"
event if I required uuid in global scope or jest.mock("uuid"....), is there a way to take off this error ?

Answer (score 0):

Now, I have a idea to solve this problem using a service injected into directive, in service we can detect if uuid is available, if not, we can use another method to generate id, and then in jest, we can mock this service, this will solve the problem, but I was still looking forward to other simple solutions

I find another way:

```js
const uuid = require('uuid');
Object.defineProperty(globalThis, 'uuid', {
  value: {
    v4: arr => uuid.v4()
  }
});
```

Don't forget to `npm install uuid` in your test folder